# How to download files from Gitlab account using java

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am writing one utility job in java to download JSON files from particular URL of Gitlab account and further process them according to requirement. I tried to do same using java-gitlab-api dependency. However, even after including below maven dependency,

I get error as :

> Missing artifact org.gitlab:java-gitlab-api:jar:1.1.8-
>   The import org.gitlab cannot be resolved.

Maven dependency I am using is :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gitlab</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-gitlab-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to update, clean maven project but nothing worked. Anyone has an idea of how can I rectify issues and download files from gitlab account.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use appropriate maven java-gitlab-api version(s). There is most recent version is available too. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gitlab/java-gitlab-api/1.1.8 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gitlab/java-gitlab-api

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gitlab/java-gitlab-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gitlab</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-gitlab-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: As I am writing one job in java to download JSON files from particular GitLab URL, what steps are required to do so in java? I have GitLab's username, password with me.